# Looking up programming language construct examples in a codebase

Tags: linux, open-source, web-apps

I have an ever evolving programming language. Like C++, it has a [feature creep](https://www.shopify.com/uk/partners/blog/feature-creep):

> Feature creep, more commonly known as scope creep, refers to when you add excessive features to a product that make it too complicated or difficult to use. Any additional features you introduce into your product add to the complexity of your design. In turn, this can diminish the usability of your product.

There's no well-written syntax for the language as it is extensible. To learn it, it is educating to find code examples of the language constructs -- the documentation does not have too much examples.

I can well develop some regular-expression-ridden shell scripts to solve this problem, but I guess there are some already written software for this. I would like to give the codebase as tarballs and it would be nice if it could search on github and bitbucket. I would like to see an output of full examples, not only URLs. Webapps are nice but the best would be to have this on Linux as open source software.

What do you recommend to use to solve this problem?

Comment: "There's no well-written syntax for the language as it is extensible." Really? You can extend the Syntax of your programming language via extensions?

Comment: @ThomasWeller yes, it does not have a BNF syntax. It is an ever evolving target.